# Nokogiri: need to turn markup partitioned by `hr` into divs

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Given markup inside an HTML document that looks like this

```
<h3>test</h3>
<p>test</p>
<hr/>
<h3>test2</h3>
<p>test2</p>
<hr/>
```

I'd like to to produce this

```
<div>
  <h3>test</h3>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>test2</h3>
  <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

What's the most elegant way to do with with Nokogiri?

Comment: You haven't accepted, upvoted, or even commented on any answers so far. Have we not yet solved your question satisfactorily?

Comment: Sorry I'm on a deadline and haven't had time to confirm the solutions yet. I'll try to get around to it tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Reworked answer to be a bit cleaner.
**Edit2**: Small rewrite to shorten by two lines

```
require 'nokogiri'    
doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<ENDHTML
  <h3>test</h3>
  <p>test</p>
  <hr/>
  <h3>test2</h3>
  <p>test2</p>
  <hr/>
ENDHTML

body = doc.at_css('body')         # Created by parsing as HTML
kids = body.xpath('./*')          # Every child of the body
body.inner_html = ""              # Empty the body now that we have our nodes

div = (body << "<div>").first     # Create our first container in the body
kids.each do |node|               # For every child that was in the body...
  if node.name=='hr'              
    div = (body << '<div>').first # Create a new container for stuff
  else                            
    div << node                   # Move this into the last container
  end                             
end                               
div.remove unless div.child       # Get rid of a trailing, empty div

puts body.inner_html
#=> <div>
#=> <h3>test</h3>
#=> <p>test</p>
#=> </div>
#=> <div>
#=> <h3>test2</h3>
#=> <p>test2</p>
#=> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses Ruby 1.9.2's [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001523) to split the children into sections and also exercises Nokogiri's `NodeSet` class:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<ENDHTML
  <h3>test</h3>
  <p>test</p>
  <hr/>
  <h3>test2</h3>
  <p>test2</p>
  <hr/>
ENDHTML

result = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new( doc,
  doc.xpath('//body/*').chunk do |n|
    n.name=='hr'
  end.reject do |matched,nodes|
    matched
  end.map do |matched,nodes|
    doc.create_element('div').tap do |div|
      div << Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new( doc, nodes )
    end
  end )

puts result
#=> <div>
#=> <h3>test</h3>
#=> <p>test</p>
#=> </div>
#=> <div>
#=> <h3>test2</h3>
#=> <p>test2</p>
#=> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd go about it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<h3>test</h3>
<p>test</p>
<hr/>
<h3>test2</h3>
<p>test2</p>
<hr/>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc2 = Nokogiri::HTML('<body />')
doc2_body = doc2.at('body')

doc.search('//h3 | //p').each_slice(2) do |ns| 
  nodeset = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(doc2, ns)
  div = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('div', doc2)
  div.add_child(nodeset)
  doc2_body.add_child(div) 
end

puts doc2_body.inner_html

# >> <div>
# >> <h3>test</h3>
# >> <p>test</p>
# >> </div>
# >> <div>
# >> <h3>test2</h3>
# >> <p>test2</p>
# >> </div>
```

Comment: You presume that the markup is only what is shown in the sample, one `h3` and `p` per section, instead of generally-delimited `hr` content. You may be correct, but this seems a rather fragile approach that will break when some innocent copy editor happens to add a second paragraph or such.

Comment: All we can go by is the OPs sample and requested output. Presuming an OP doesn't know anything about the problem they asked about and are trying to fix seems to be a bigger problem.