# Ruby group hashes by value of key

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash, mongodb-ruby

I have an array, which is output by a map/reduce method performed by MongoDB, it looks something like this:

```
[{"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>299.0}, 
{"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>244.0}, 
{"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>1.0, "count"=>204.0}, 
{"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>510.0}, 
{"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>437.0}, 
{"minute"=>0.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>469.0}, 
{"minute"=>0.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>477.0}, 
{"minute"=>15.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>481.0}, 
{"minute"=>15.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>401.0}, 
{"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>468.0}, 
{"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>448.0}, 
{"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>0.0, "count"=>485.0}, 
{"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "type"=>10.0, "count"=>518.0}]
```

You'll notice that there are three distinct values for `type`, in this case `0`, `1`, and `2`,  now want to do is group this array of hashes by the value its `type` key, so for example this array would end out looking like:

```
{
  :type_0 => [
    {"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>299.0}, 
    {"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>510.0}, 
    {"minute"=>0.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>469.0}, 
    {"minute"=>15.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>481.0}, 
    {"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>468.0}, 
    {"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>485.0}
  ],

  :type_1 => [
    {"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>204.0}
  ],

  :type_10 => [
    {"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>244.0}, 
    {"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>15.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>437.0},
    {"minute"=>0.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>477.0}, 
    {"minute"=>15.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>401.0}, 
    {"minute"=>30.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>448.0}, 
    {"minute"=>45.0, "hour"=>16.0, "date"=>5.0, "month"=>9.0, "year"=>2011.0, "count"=>518.0}
  ]
}
```

*so I know these example arrays are really large, but I think it may be a more simple problem than I'm making it out to be*

So basically each array of hashes would be grouped by the value of its `type` key, and then returned as a hash with an array for each type, any help at all would be really really helpful, even just some helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to split arrays into multiple small arrays in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686493/best-way-to-split-arrays-into-multiple-small-arrays-in-ruby)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
array.group_by {|x| x['type']}
```

or if you want the symbol key things you could even

```
array.group_by {|x| "type_#{x['type']}".to_sym}
```

I think this best expresses "So basically each **array of hashes** would be **grouped by the value of its type key**, and then **returned as a hash with an array for each type**", even if it leaves the `:type` key alone in the output hashes.

Comment: it doesn't produce the output in the question, and doesn't work in Ruby 1.8

Comment: This will group, but it doesn't delete the 'type' in the response. I don't mind that, as it's simple, but it doesn't answer the question, tbh.

Answer (score 2):

```
by_type = {}

a.each do |h|
   type = h.delete("type").to_s
   # type = ("type_" + type ).to_sym

   by_type[ type ] ||= []
   by_type[ type ] << h      # note: h is modified, without "type" key

end
```

Note: slightly different hash keys here, i used the type values directly as the key

if you have to have the hash-keys as in your example, you can add the line that is commented out.

---

P.S.: I just saw Tapio's solution -- it is very nice and short!  Note that it only works with Ruby >= 1.9

Comment: why not just `a.group_by {|x| x['type']}` ?

Comment: In that it doesn't remove the 'type' key? I don't think that would really matter, would it?

Comment: @Tapio: in his example, he was expecting that the "type" key is removed from the hashes along the way... Yes, I agree, doesn't really matter .. group_by() is new and yummy, thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
mangled = a.group_by { |h| h['type'].to_i }.each_with_object({ }) do |(k,v), memo|
    tk = ('type_' + k.to_s).to_sym
    memo[tk] = v.map { |h| h = h.dup; h.delete('type'); h }
end
```

Or if you don't care about preserving the original data:

```
mangled = a.group_by { |h| h['type'].to_i }.each_with_object({ }) do |(k,v), memo|
    tk = ('type_' + k.to_s).to_sym
    memo[tk] = v.map { |h| h.delete('type'); h } # Drop the h.dup in here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`group_by` *collects an enumerable into sets, grouped by the result of a block*. You are not constrained to simply get the key's value in this block, so if you would like to omit the `'type'` in those sets you can do it, like in:

```
array.group_by {|x| "type_#{x.delete('type').to_i}".to_sym}
```

This will result exactly into what you asked.

**Advanced:** This goes a little out of scope of the question, but if you want to preserve the original array, you must duplicate every object inside it. This will do the trick:

```
array.map(&:dup).group_by {|x| "type_#{x.delete('type').to_i}".to_sym}
```