# Split an array in ruby based on some condition

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array named `@level1` which has a value like this:

```
[
  [3.1, 4],
  [3.0, 7],
  [2.1, 5],
  [2.0, 6],
  [1.9, 3]
]
```

I want to split this into two arrays such that the first array (`@arr1`) contains the values till `2.1` and the second array (`@arr2`) contains values after it.

After doing that, I would reverse-sort my second array by doing something like this:

```
@arr2 = @arr2.sort_by { |x, _| x }.reverse
```

I would then like to merge this array to `@arr1`. Can someone help me how to split the array and then merge them together?

Comment: can you show us your expected output?

Comment: `@arr1 = { [3.1, 4], [3.0, 7]}`
`@arr2 = { [2.1, 5], [2.0, 6], [1.9, 3]}`

Then I will reverse sort @arr2 which will give me the follwoing:

`@arr2 = { [1.9, 3] , [2.0, 6], [2.1, 5]}`

And then i would merge these 2 arrays

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to split arrays into multiple small arrays in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686493/best-way-to-split-arrays-into-multiple-small-arrays-in-ruby)

Comment: by values after you mean values greater than 2.1?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try the [partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method

```
@arr1, @arr2 = @level1.partition { |x| x[0] > 2.1 }
```

The condition there may need to be adjusted, since that wasn't very well specified in the question, but that should provide a good starting point.

Comment: You probably want to use `x[0] <= 2.1`

Comment: @texasbruce No, arr1 is supposed to contain the larger values, so the condition should not be reversed.  In any case, since the question didn't do a very good job of specifying the exact condition I'm not too concerned about getting that exactly correct here.

Comment: Guys it says : undefined method `>' for ["3.1"]:Array

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
arr = [
  ["3.1", 4],
  ["3.0", 7],
  ["2.1", 5],
  ["2.0", 6],
  ["1.9", 3]
]

arr1, arr2 = arr.inject([[], []]) do |f,a|
  a.first.to_f <= 2.1 ? f.last << a : f.first << a; f
end

arr = arr1 + arr2.reverse
# => [["3.1", 4], ["3.0", 7], ["1.9", 3], ["2.0", 6], ["2.1", 5]]
```

Comment: It says undefined method `<=' for ["3.0"]:Array

Comment: the code in my answer works well on 1.8.7(as on all other versions), here is [the proof](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=split-an-array-in-ruby-based-on-some-condition.rb&run=true&versions=1.8.7-p370)

Comment: I think the first element that is 3.1, 3.0, 2.1 and so on, in each row is considered as a string. How do I convert that to an integer. It is not able to compare because it a a string.

Comment: ok i managed to convert that to float and it works now. Thanks